# balancer data pipes

Tags: mongodb

How is the data moving from a source shard to a target shard when balancer wants to move it? does that data move to monogoS from the source shard and then inserted into target shard from the mongoS or will the source shard and target shard open up a dedicated connection and move the data between themselves and mongoS just monitor that?

if that is the second case, does this mean that there is a balancer logic running on each shard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The balancing happens by mongos. Mongos will trigger a balancing run every 15 seconds. If it finds that chunk distribution is uneven it will select a chunk to migrate and initiate that migration. Once it reachs that point the mongos/balancer is done. From here on out the actual migration of data happens between the two mongod instances/shards.

So, there's no balancing logic running on the shards but the shards do execute the migration amongst themselves once initiated by the balancer.

Comment: So is it the target shard that runs the migration logic or the source shard? What mechanism is use? I mean does the migration logic uses the generic monogd API to load the chunk and then move it? I basically want to understand how the migration happens as it gets in the middle of my fast batch inserts and causes lots of page faulting and slowing down my batch insert.

Comment: The source shard runs the logic. The target shard "blindly" trusts the source shards instructions. It does not use the generic API but uses an internal multi-phase commit and retry system to make sure the migration is done safely and doesn't result in inconsistent situations. As you can imagine there are quite a few edge cases to have to take into account. It slows down your batch inserts because it it has to keep migration all the writes to your hot chunk to the moved version on the target shard. At some point it will lock writes to the source chunk altogether and reject the writes.

Comment: Note that when I say "reject writes" it means mongos is notified the writes were attempted on a stale chunk and it will automatically retry the writes on the receiving chunk/shard. Page faults and such are a natural result of the receiving side having to swap the appropriate disk segments/pages into memory. You can configure balancing to only happen at certain time intervals if that helps.